# What is a better word for tradable?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I have a feeling the word starts with a d, and is used a lot in sports language. When a players or something could be traded, they (being media) would use this word.

Here’s a sentence...

“Among NFL teams which player(s) would be the most (d)_____ to be traded to a different team?”

Comment: What exactly do you *mean* by "tradable"? For example, it could be the player you'd most like to sell off / be shut of because he's the *worst* player. OR it could be the *best* player (who should fetch the highest transfer fee). OR the player who's "easiest" to trade, because of things like his nationality, visa / employment status, or whatever. OR... OR... But the most obvious word for your cited context is just ***likely***.

Comment: "Valuable" comes to mind, but it doesn't really fit the criteria..

Comment: I was thinking of expendable. That’s word. Someone said it, so whoever did thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expendable or dispensable would fit the parameters of your restrictions. Often used in sports language and verbiage

Comment: Wouldn't that rather mean that the person in question would not be missed in the team if sold?